# How to mix ambient and non-ambient typescript definition files

Tags: typescript, module, node-modules, typescript-typings, tsd

I have an older typescript project which uses the /typings/tsd.json method of handling .d.ts files, and which also uses Typescript's `module` keyword to compile source into javascript's IIFE module pattern.  The module setting in tsconfig.json (commonjs/amd/etc.) is ignored by that keyword.

For a demo, I am adding to this project some newer typescript code which uses the more typical method of `import` and `export` keywords with a SystemJS module loader, with .d.ts files in /node_modules/@types/.

After some Gulp/SystemJS gymnastics, it all works together at runtime and I'm on track to hit my deadline. But I am having trouble at compile-time in one scenario which I'd like to solve.

When I modify the older code to use a class (a model) from the newer code, I'd like the old code to know about the .d.ts of the new code.  So I added to the top of the old code's file `/// <reference path="../../newercode/feature4/models/NewerModels.d.ts"/>`.  (Alternately, I put the same line in tsd.d.ts but I get the same result.)

The compiler complains my old code "has or is using private name 'NewModel'".

Inside NewerModels.d.ts the `import` and `export` keywords are still there, while none of the .d.ts files already in /typings/ use those keywords.  Those keywords are the culprit for the spurious compiler error.

The legacy project wants ambient .d.ts files, newer code produces non-ambient.

Is there anything I can do about it?

Comment: I would suggest instead of keep using `tsd`, migrate to use `@types`. You should be able to do that in one shot.

Comment: The .d.ts file you get for a package differs depending on where you get it from. If I did that, then all of the .d.ts files would have import/export keywords, so none of the legacy code would compile at all.

Comment: The newer files you get from `@types` should have the same syntax. The original library is still the same CommonJS library (unless that change, then you need to deal with versioning). `tsd` gets files from DefinitelyTyped and same as `@types`. TS team did a reasonable good job and converting the format. Give it a try to see if it works.

Comment: On the other hand, the error you see is complaining you don't have `NewModel` exported. Maybe you didn't include it in your `package.json/dist`?

Comment: Good point, but legacy project is using legacy .d.ts, so even if the same .d.ts file is received from both sources nowadays, the old project compiles against the old .d.ts which lacks the troublesome keywords.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My current solution isn't ideal, but it works for demo purposes.

I create a new folder under */typings/*, called */feature4/*, and copy the relevant *.d.ts* files into there.  Edit them to remove `export` keywords, modify as needed to remove `import` keywords, and replace the `class` keyword with `interface` to prevent the patched legacy code from attempting a raw `new NewerModel()` call.

That last bit obviously wouldn't work because the newer classes don't actually exist on the global namespace, and the change from `class` to `interface` helps discourage this.  Since I'm mainly grabbing models, an interface loses no functionality other than requiring `new NewerModel()` be written as `<NewerModel>{}`, but I still get compile-time checking on the properties of the model, which is 95% of what I wanted anyway.

I also have a few services that are treated the same way, but calling methods on them still work due to Dependency Injection.  The services were never called from the global namespace to begin with.

This solution will obviously have a problem if someone changes */newercode/feature4/models/NewerModels.ts*, but 1) there shouldn't be any between now and the deadline, and 2) if it's really an issue I could create a Gulp task to automate the copying and editing of the *.d.ts* files on each build.